# object_manipulation vs GraspIt vs OpenRave

Tags: ros, object-manipulation, openrave, grasping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is an open-ended question aimed at grasp planning and object manipulation. Of the object_manipulation pipeline, the libraries provided by GraspIt and the libraries provided by OpenRave, which are the most robust when it comes to grasp planning and object manipulation?

GraspIt and OpenRave seem to primarily offer a grasping simulation environment, but it's my understanding that they also have some built-in grasp planning and object manipulation capability.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10770/object_manipulation-vs-graspit-vs-openrave/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2011-07-29

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All the libraries you mention are being actively worked on and maintained. Each library has its own focus and set of things it does well. Depending on your particular use case, you should look for whether the library does everything you want.

What kind of objects are you doing grasp planning for? object_manipulation can do grasp planning for point clouds, GraspIt does it for meshes, and so on. The motion planning stacks in ROS offer a complete pipeline from planning to execution. OpenRave can do fast IK for most arms. Depending on what you want, one or the other library might be more suitable for you.

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2011-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4